# Why are there so many users that are unable to set and use their monitor's optimal resolution?

Tags: discussion

I have seen so many questions that ask something to effect of:

**How to apply resolution that isn't available in "Display Settings"?**

Almost all have not been solved. Such questions have been asked for the past 10 years.

Are these problems to do with poor levels of kernel support for monitors? Or some other reason?

Why is it that there is no way around this, apart from using `xrandr` - which often result in **BadName** or **gamma failed** errors?

Comment: N.B. links to these questions often help....

Comment: @Wilf simply search for the display tag...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because some monitors poorly report their capabilities in EDID.

Some vendors provide Windows monitor "drivers" that fix the issue instead of doing it well on hardware level.